Resolve undefined references to library linked by dlopen
When using
void *ptr = dlopen(path_to_shared_object,RTLD_NOW)

"all undefined symbols in the shared object are resolved before dlopen() returns" (man page).
Is there an analogous way to summarily resolve all undefined symbols in the caller of dlopen against symbols in the shared object? One can of course do that explicitly using dlsym, but I want to make it as simple as possible.
I tried all meaningful combinations of flags in dlopen and also dlmopen(LM_ID_BASE, ...)


Is there an analogous way to summarily resolve all undefined symbols in the caller of dlopen against symbols in the shared object?

This will automatically happen (as the program below demonstrates), but will result in exceedingly fragile code, so best avoided.
// main.c
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  void *h = dlopen("./foo.so", RTLD_GLOBAL|RTLD_LAZY);

  if (h == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
    exit(1);
  }
  int (*foo)() = dlsym(h, "foo");

  return foo();
}

// foo.c
#include <dlfcn.h>

int bar();
int foo()
{
  void *h = dlopen("./bar.so", RTLD_GLOBAL|RTLD_NOW);
  return bar();  // This resolves to bar() in bar.so
}

// bar.c
int bar() { return 42; }

gcc -g -shared -fPIC -o bar.so bar.c &&
gcc -g -shared -fPIC -o foo.so foo.c -ldl &&
gcc -g main.c -ldl &&
./a.out

echo $?
42

What's fragile about this?

The dlopen in main must be done with RTLD_LAZY, otherwise that dlopen will fail with unresolved bar.
The call to bar only succeeds because dlopen brings definition of bar into the linker scope. If you call bar before dlopen, the program will die with symbol lookup error: ./foo.so: undefined symbol: bar.
foo can only be linked into a shared library, attempts to link it into the main executable will fail with unresolved bar.


I'd say there are no undefined symbols in the caller of dlopen, which is main in a.out; the undefined symbol bar is in foo.so.
